# Use Meta (Super) for all keyboard shortcuts in KDE (at least for KDE apps)?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, kde

I come from the Mac so I'm used to use the Command-key (Windows-key) on my keyboard to initiate shortcuts like Ctrl+C, Ctrl+P etc.

Especially in the Konsole I miss the convenience of the Mac shortcuts, where in Linux Ctrl+C would cancel a programm, while Win+C would copy under Mac.

Is there a way to switch all the KDE apps to use the Windows key instead of control, like globally? I remember that it was once possible, but I can't seem to find the option for KDE 5.10 anywhere and I do not want to reconfigure each and every programm individually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In KDE, shortcuts are easily defined via System Settings > Workspace > Shortcuts > Standard Shortcuts. I was successfully able to change the shortcut from Ctl+C to Meta+C easily. All known shortcuts can be changed via that method.

Comment: But then I'd have to change every shortcut individually, right?

Comment: If there's a global way to edit these easily, I have not found it. I suspect it likely is more trouble than it's worth, but if you really want to try it, I suspect looking at the file HOME//.config/khotkeysrc would be the best place to start.